# Neural network : Unexpected matrix size at the output of each layer

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to learn Neural networks and the math associated on my own.

I tried to code a simple NN and compare it with my hand calculations, but there's a discrepency that I'm not able to understand and I hope that you can help me.

1. I wrote the following NN (from this [tutorial](https://pythonalgos.com/create-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-3/))

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

class Network:
    # sizes is a list of the number of nodes in each layer
    def __init__(self, sizes, biases, weights):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = biases
        self.weights = weights

    def feedforward(self, a):
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a) + b)
        return a
```

2. I initialized a 3 layer NN : 2-input, 3-hidden, 1-output

```
sizes = [2,3,1]
biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x,y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
net = Network(sizes, biases, weights)
```

3. After calculating by hand the outputs of each layer, I compared it with my program by debugging the `a` variable in the `feedforward` function

I found these 2 discrepencies that I can't explain

1. In my program, the output of the hidden layer is a 3x3 matrix. While I expected a 1x3 matrix (each of the 3 hidden neurons outputs a single value). My values matched the diagonal of that 3x3 matrix, but I don't understand what the other values mean
2. The output of the last layer is a 1x3 matrix, While I expected a 1x1 matrix (one output neuron, one value). I tried summing them up but I couldn't get to the final value I was expecting

There's surely something I'm fundamentally missing. Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the input should be `(2,1)`. If it's `(1,2)` (e.g. can be caused by the following initialization: `np.random.randn(2)`), the first hidden layer calculation may return an 3x3 matrix because of *broadcasting* typically implemented in numerical libraries.

```
r = np.dot(w, a) + b -> (1x3) + (3x1) --> (3x3)
```

You can't add two vectors of different sizes mathematically, but libraries make it possible to ease calculations. In this case, the result matrix elements would look like following
`r_{ij}=c_j+d_i`
where `c` is the first summand and `d` is the second summand. This operation is called broadcasting. The smaller dimension is broadcasted across the corresponding one in the other summand, which leaves us with a 3x3 matrix.

It is why the diagonal elements are the ones you're looking for since `r_{ii}=c_i+d_i`, which are the results you actually propagate to the next layer.

With these dimensions mismatches, it's quite expected that the output layer dimensions are wrong as well.